# Cannot find created directory in C#

Tags: c#, io

I use:

```
public const string WbPlanDirPath = "\\SavedWbPlans";

if (!Directory.Exists(WbPlanDirPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(WbPlanDirPath);
}
```

to create a directory. Although, it seems to work fine (no exceptions being thrown) I cannot find the folder/directory anywhere in the file system. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Just try to print path of directory you are created.

Comment: You could also print the directory maybe via console/messagebox with `(new DirectoryInfo(WbPlanDirPath)).FullName`

Answer (score 2):

```
"\\SavedWbPlans"
```

Notice the backslash at the very beginning. In the context of paths in Windows, this refers to the *root* of a drive.

So, the directory is very likely created *on the root of your drive*, depending where the working directory is.

For example, if the working directory is `D:\Somewhere\in\the\drive\`, it will be created as `D:\SavedWbPlans`.

---

If you are trying to create a directory in the same directory where the program is located at, use the following code instead:

```
string directory_of_program = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string WbPlanDirPath = Path.Combine(directory_of_program, "SavedWbPlans");

if (!Directory.Exists(WbPlanDirPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(WbPlanDirPath);
}
```

Comment: Nice and clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It should be created on the root level for the volume for the current directory. Check `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

That's making a directory in `\SavedWebPlans` off the root of the volume with the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the same **parent directory** (the directory containing your program) as your program.

Instead of `"\\SavedWbPlans";`

Use `"SavedWbPlans";`

That will save it in the current directory (the same directory as your program)

Answer (score 0):

`CreateDirectory` returns a `DirectoryInfo` object that points to the created directory.

Check its properties to find out where it was created.